# Minishift - Help to configure with NAT and Proxy

Tags: hyper-v, minishift

I'm trying to setup desesperatly Minishift desesperatly in a Corporate Network.
I can't create my Virtual Switch as External, then I'm trying to start Minishift with Internal Switch and Proxy settings.

Configuration.

```
Minishift version : minishift-1.13.1
SET MINISHIFT_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL="y"
SET HYPERV_VIRTUAL_SWITCH="MiniShift2"
ISO URL centos
```

I have followed this tutorial to create a NAT :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network

```
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "MiniShift2" -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex "myIndex"
New-NetNat -Name MyNATnetwork -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/24
```

Then I start Minishift :

```
minishift.exe start   --show-libmachine-logs -v1 --iso-url centos  --network-ipaddress 192.168.0.2   --http-proxy MyProxyHTTP --https-proxy=MyProxyHTPPs
```

Then I start Minishift :

```
minishift.exe start   --show-libmachine-logs -v1 --iso-url centos  --network-ipaddress 192.168.0.2   --http-proxy MyProxyHTTP --https-proxy=MyProxyHTPPs

-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'hyperv' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if Hyper-V driver is installed ... OK
-- Checking if Hyper-V driver is configured to use a Virtual Switch ... OK
-- Checking if user is a member of the Hyper-V Administrators group ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'hyperv' hypervisor ...
-- Minishift VM will be configured with ...
   Memory:    2 GB
   vCPUs :    2
   Disk size: 20 GB
-- Attempting to set network settings ...
   Device:      eth0
   IP Address:  192.168.0.2/24
   Nameservers: 8.8.8.8
-- Starting Minishift VM ....Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(minishift) Downloading D:\XXX\minishift_dir\cache\boot2docker.iso from file://D:/XXX/minishift_dir/cache/iso/centos/v1.6.1/minishift-centos7.iso...
.(minishift) Creating SSH key...
(minishift) Creating VM...
(minishift) Using switch "MiniShift2"
(minishift) Creating VHD
.....(minishift) Starting VM...
(minishift) Waiting for host to start...
......Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
....Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with minishift...

   Setting hostname ...
.OK
..Copying certs to the local machine directory...
..Copying certs to the remote machine...
.Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
...Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
-- Setting proxy information ... .OK
 OK
-- Checking for IP address ... OK
-- Checking if external host is reachable from the Minishift VM ...
   Pinging 8.8.8.8 ... FAIL
   VM is unable to ping external host
-- Checking HTTP connectivity from the VM ...
   Retrieving http://minishift.io/index.html ... FAIL
   VM cannot connect to external URL with HTTP
-- Checking if persistent storage volume is mounted ... OK
-- Checking available disk space ... 1% used OK
   Importing 'openshift/origin:v3.7.1' . CACHE MISS
   Importing 'openshift/origin-docker-registry:v3.7.1' . CACHE MISS
   Importing 'openshift/origin-haproxy-router:v3.7.1'  CACHE MISS
-- OpenShift cluster will be configured with ...
   Version: v3.7.1
-- Checking 'oc' support for startup flags ...
   http-proxy ... OK
   https-proxy ... OK
   no-proxy ... OK
   routing-suffix ... OK
   host-config-dir ... OK
   host-data-dir ... OK
   host-pv-dir ... OK
   host-volumes-dir ... OK
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.7.1 ...
Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.7.1
Image pull complete
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... OK
-- Checking Docker version ... OK
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v3.7.1 image ...
   Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.7.1
   Image pull complete
-- Checking Docker daemon configuration ... OK
-- Checking for available ports ... FAIL
   Error: Cannot get TCP port information from Kubernetes host
   Caused By:
     Error: cannot create container using image openshift/origin:v3.7.1
     Caused By:
       Error: Error: No such image: openshift/origin:v3.7.1
Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster.
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you say you can't create your Virtual Switch as External? I am trying to do it and I get the VM with the same IP address as my physical machine. Is it the reason?